# How can I have threads work together on a single file?

Tags: java, multithreading, caesar-cipher

I have this caesar cipher that I made as a project way back 1.5 years ago as a project and I'll be reusing it since I'm tasked to create a program that utilizes threading. This from a post that I deleted because I failed to provide proper details btw.

Here's my progress so far.

```
    //Enter the file name and/or path. 
    //Note: This is not case-sensitive but enter the file name and/or path correctly.
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    String filename = in.nextLine();
    
    //Enters the encryption key.
    System.out.print("Enter your key: ");
    int key = in.nextInt();
    


    File file = new File(filename);
    
    byte[] filebyte = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(filebyte);
            
            thread1.start(filebyte);
            thread2.start(filebyte);
            thread3.start(filebyte);
            thread4.start(filebyte);
            
            //Then written back into the file.
            FileOutputStream newfile = new FileOutputStream(file);
            newfile.write(filebyte);
            newfile.close();
            System.out.println("File encrypted successfuly.");
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

2 of the 4 threads that will do the encryption. What each thread does is to start shifting based on where each of their `i` starts then jump 4 bytes and shifts the current byte. (Sorry. I had a hard time wording this.)

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {
    private int key;
    publlic Thread4(int enkey) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public void run() {
        //The characters inside the array are shifted here.
        for (int i = 0; i < filebyte.length; i+=4) {
            filebyte[i] = (byte) ((filebyte[i] + key) % 256);
        }
    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread {
    private int key;
    publlic Thread4(int enkey) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public void run() {
        //The characters inside the array are shifted here.
        for (int i = 1; i < filebyte.length; i+=4) {
            filebyte[i] = (byte) ((filebyte[i] + key) % 256);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I have no idea how can I make these threads work together on the file's `filebyte` directly. If I try to have the threads return the `filebyte` after shifting, it would end up with the threads trying to return 4 different versions of the `filebyte`.

Here's how my program should work btw:

Text/File: Hello World

```
thread1 - H   o   r   shifted I   p   s
thread2 -  e       l  shifted  f   !   m
thread3 -   l   W   d shifted   m   X   e
thread4 -    l   o    shifted    m   p
```

After the threads finished encrypting: Ifmmp!Xpsme

Comment: `volatile byte[] filebyte = new byte[(int) file.length()];`

Comment: Would each of the methods transfer their changes to the file when they are going to return the `filebyte` back to main?

Comment: Check your ***for*** loops carefully, are they running as you expect they would be? In your case, you don't even need a ***volatile*** keyword. If you want people to help you, you need to post more info especially your unaltered file, your expected result, how you want each byte to be processed, or you just want to speed up the shifting process.

Comment: I added how my program should work. Regarding whether the program is running, no. Since I attempted moving the part of the program which does the shifting to the threads which makes it not functional as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you play with and understand how it works.

```
class ObscureThread implements Runnable
{
    private byte[] bytes;
    private int key;
    private int index;
    private int increment;
    public Thread thread;

    public final ObscureThread(byte[] bytes, int key, int threadQuantity, int threadIndex) {
        this.bytes= bytes;
        this.key = key;
        increment = threadQuantity; //How many threads?
        index = threadIndex; //threadIndex must starts from 0.
        thread = new Thread(this); //Make sure to use "this" and NOT just Thread().
        thread.start(); //Start the thread. run() will be called.
    }
    public final void run() {
        for(int i=index; i<bytes.length; i+=increment) {
            bytes[i] = (byte)((bytes[i] + key) % 256);
        }
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d' };
        int key = 1;
        int numOfThreads = 4; //Doesn't have to be 4.
        for(int i=0; i<numOfThreads; i++) {
            ObscureThread thread = new ObscureThread(bytes, key, numOfThreads, i);
            thread.thread.join(); //Wait for the threads to finish.
        }
        for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.print((char) bytes[i]);
        } //Ifmmp!Xpsme
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```